# A question about fractional derivatives

Tags: fractional-calculus

What would be the fractional derivative of any order 'b' of the function

$ (a-x) $ ?

My guess is: $$ \frac{d^{s}}{dx^{s}}(a-x)^{-1}= \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(a-x)^{s+1}} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't think that your guess is correct. The corresponding Rieman-Liouville fractional integral involves a Gauss hypergeometric function: hypergeometric2F1(1,1;1-s;x/a)/(a*(x^s)*Gamma(1-s))

Comment: Your guess should be correct if the definition of the fractional derivatives was based on the Weyl's transform instead of the Rieman-Liouville transform, which should be not the usual definition.

Comment: Function 1-x or 1/(a-x)?

Answer (score 1):

It is not sadly.  The more correct answer is much more complicated, and is given as so:

$$\frac{d^s}{dx^s}\frac1{a-x}=\frac{d^s}{dx^s}\frac{-1}{x-a}=\frac{-(x-a)^{-1-s}\left[\ln(x-a)-\gamma-\psi^{(0)}(-s)\right]}{\Gamma(-s)}$$

And for $s\in\mathbb N$,

$$=\lim_{k\to s}\frac{d^s}{dx^s}\frac{-1}{x-a}=\frac{-(x-a)^{-1-k}\left[\ln(x-a)-\gamma-\psi^{(0)}(-k)\right]}{\Gamma(-k)}$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\psi^{(0)}$ is the digamma function